# Ember Data Undefined in Template But Accessible in Console

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am relatively new to ember and am just taking a look at it for the first time, I am using ember-cli-mirage as a mock server and am having some issues.

In my models/groups.js I have

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  serverType: DS.attr('string', {defaultValue: 'Web Server'}),
  protectionMode: DS.attr('string', {defaultValue: 'High'}),
  protectionLevel: DS.attr('string', {defaultValue: '=)'}),
  bps: DS.attr('number'),
  pps: DS.attr('number'),
  protectedHosts: DS.attr('string', {defaultValue: '1.0.0.0'}),
  lastModified: DS.attr('number', {defaultValue: 1}),
  complete: DS.attr('string')
});
```

I originally did not have default values in anywhere but once I added them content showed up in my templates for serverType, protectionMode, protectionLevel but not lastModified or protectedHosts

My mirage/config.js

```
export default function() {
  this.get('/groups', function(db, request) {
    console.log(db.groups)
    return {
      data: db.groups.map(attrs => (
        {type: 'groups', id: attrs.id, attributes: attrs}
      ))
    };
  });

  this.post('/groups', function(db, request) {
    let attrs = JSON.parse(request.requestBody);
    let group = db.groups.insert(attrs);
    return {
      data: {
        type: 'groups',
        id: group.id,
        attributes: group
      }
    };
  });

  this.patch('/groups/:id', function(db, request) {
    let attrs = JSON.parse(request.requestBody);
    let group = db.groups.update(attrs.data.id, attrs.data.attributes);
    return {
      data: {
        type: 'groups',
        id: group.id,
        attributes: group
      }
    };
  });

  this.del('/groups/:id');
}
```

The console logging I am doing in the /groups get is showing all of the correct data from my mirage/factories

mirage/factories/groups.js

```
import Mirage, {faker} from 'ember-cli-mirage';

export default Mirage.Factory.extend({  
    name(i) { return `Protection Group ${i + 1}`; },
    serverType(i) { return `Custom Server Type ${i + 1}`;},
    protectionMode: 'High',
    protectionLevel: '=)',
    lastModified(i) { return `${i+1} Weeks`; },
    bps(i) { return parseInt(Math.floor((Math.random() * i) + 100 * i)) },
    pps(i) { return parseInt(Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + i)) },
    protectedHosts(i) { return `10.1.2.1${i+1}`; },
    complete: false
});
```

Anyone have any idea why some data is showing up as undefined and some is not and why some default values are working but some are not?

Comment: Did you find answer? Stack same problem...

Answer (score 0):

For `protectedHosts` and `lastModified` you spelled `defaultValue` incorrectly. You have `defualtValue` (the `u` and `a` are reversed).

Comment: Yeah I realized that after posting, but it still doesn't explain why my data in the console reflects that which is being created by the factory and in the Template for Name, pps, and bps, but not for the rest of the attributes